# Vue-Router returns 404 in google ADS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http, google-analytics

I have some problems with setting google ads to my project. My vue router is working in history mode and when I open any URL directly (e.g `mysite.com/category/phone`) it works fine. But in ads.google.com when I try to add these URLs as targets it's declined because google receives error 404 on HTTP request to these URLs. Maybe it's because I'm using Vue.js app inside the Yii2 template? Also, I am receiving meta tags and some URLs that need to be served from the backend before router init.

```
Vue.axios.get('/api/meta').then(response => {
   const routes = [...defining routes here...];
   ...
   const router = new VueRouter ({
    mode: 'history',
    routes,
    scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
        return { x: 0, y: 0 };
    }
   });


  const app = new Vue({
    template: '',
    router,
  }).$mount('#app');

});
```